# Do a task in background with Ionic (display call screen when app is closed)

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, webrtc, voip

I have an application who receive calls via WebRTC and WebSockets. The call works well when the app is open.

When the app is closed, we receive a push notification to signal us that we have a call, but this solution isn't user friendly...

I also have a plugin to launch the default call screen of Android and iOS who works when the app is open.

My question is : how can I display the call screen (like WhatsApp) when we have a call and the app is closed ?

I saw there is VoipPush for iOS, but there is no equivalent for Android.

Is there a solution who works for iOS and Android ?

I already try on Android to use the background mode plugin for Ionic but it not working for my need : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/background-mode/

Comment: Does anyone have a track to follow?